# How can I select a widget by long pressing on it and then call a delete method (similar to WhatsApp)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am currently building a chat app. I want to know how I can achieve longpress to select and delete in a listview in flutter. The feature is similar to that of WhatsApp or telegram where you can longpress and hold to select a item to select it in a listview and then the appbar actions changes and displays a delete button.

Comment: So you can wrap the text widget with the gesture detector, this widget has a long press event you can change the state of the appbar and show specific icons to delete the item. And on deleting the item change the appbar state to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text widget with a gesture detector, there is a property `onLongPress` in this widget. The syntax would be like this

```
GestureDetector(
onLongPress:(){
//do your stuff
}
)
```